# Connection time out while accessing jsp using URLConnection

Tags: java, ajax, jsp, servlets, networking

My code is from server jsp accessing another jsp which is in clients machine and this is perfectly communicates between client machines and server with in my office network without any issue. But the same code when my server jsp is in outside office(another network) and client machines in my network, am getting connection timeout exception in server logs.
And when I connect to client machine through ajax call, i am able to get response form client.my code is below.

Java code in server jsp:

```
    URL jspUrl = new URL("...../Test.jsp");
    URLConnection servletConnection = jspUrl.openConnection();
    servletConnection.setDoOutput(true);
    servletConnection.setDoInput(true);
    servletConnection.setUseCaches(true);
    servletConnection.setDefaultUseCaches(true);
    servletConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-java-serialized-object");
    OutputStream outputStream = servletConnection.getOutputStream();
    ObjectOutputStream outputToServlet = new ObjectOutputStream(outputStream);
    outputToServlet.writeObject(object);
    outputToServlet.flush();

    InputStream inputStream = servletConnection.getInputStream();
    ObjectInputStream outputFromServlet = new ObjectInputStream(inputStream);
    readObject = outputFromServlet.readObject();
    outputFromServlet.close();
    outputToServlet.close();
```

Ajax code in server jsp which is working:

```
function callAjax
{
     if(window.XMLHttpRequest)
     {
          reqObj=new XMLHttpRequest();
     }
     else 
     {
          reqObj=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
     }
     reqObj.onreadystatechange=processfunction;
     reqObj.open("POST","./jspName.jsp?"+Id,false);
     reqObj.send(null);
}

function processfunction()
{
    try
    {
        if(reqObj.readyState==4)
        {
            if(reqObj.status == 200)
            {
                var responseString = reqObj.responseText;

            }
        }
    }
    catch(e)
    {
        //alert(e);
    }

}
```

Comment: It's not a surprise, you already know why it's happening both the machines are in different disconnected networks as you said.

Comment: But am able to connect with ajax call right? if the case is what you said, then it should not work with ajax also..

Comment: In your post you have said that you're able to make the connection when both server and client are in your office and not when server goes outside office, are you able to make the Ajax call when server is outside office ?

Comment: yes, am able to make ajax call when server is outside office.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, make sure you are connected to Internet. Then change connection time to zero i.e infinte:

```
servletConnection.setConnectTimeout(0);

//Set read time out to zero if required
servletConnection.setReadTimeout(0);
```

Comment: You are telling how to handle connection timeout, but am asking why i am getting this exception and how can i get data from another network client machine using the above mentioned java code.

Comment: Try to access the web service or server url using public IP address.