# Connection time out while accessing using URLConnection

Tags: java, ajax, jsp, stream

My code is from server jsp am accessing another jsp which is in clients machine and this is perfectly communicates between client machines and server with in my office network without any issue. But the same code when my server jsp is in outside office(another network) and client mahchines in my network, am getting connection timeout exception in server logs.
And when i connect to client machine through ajax call, i am able to get response form client.My code is below.can some one clarify the problem?

java code in server jsp:

```
    URL jspUrl = new URL("...../Test.jsp");
    URLConnection servletConnection = jspUrl.openConnection();
    servletConnection.setDoOutput(true);
    servletConnection.setDoInput(true);
    servletConnection.setUseCaches(true);
    servletConnection.setDefaultUseCaches(true);
    servletConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-java-serialized-object");
    OutputStream outputStream = servletConnection.getOutputStream();
    ObjectOutputStream outputToServlet = new ObjectOutputStream(outputStream);
    outputToServlet.writeObject(object);
    outputToServlet.flush();

    InputStream inputStream = servletConnection.getInputStream();
    ObjectInputStream outputFromServlet = new ObjectInputStream(inputStream);
    readObject = outputFromServlet.readObject();
    outputFromServlet.close();
    outputToServlet.close();
```

ajax code in server jsp which is working:

```
       function callAjax
        {
          if(window.XMLHttpRequest)
            {
                reqObj=new XMLHttpRequest();
            }
            else 
            {
                reqObj=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
            }
            reqObj.onreadystatechange=processfunction;
            reqObj.open("POST","./jspName.jsp?"+Id,false);
            reqObj.send(null);
         }
    function processfunction()
    {
        try
        {
            if(reqObj.readyState==4)
            {
                if(reqObj.status == 200)
                {
                    var responseString = reqObj.responseText;

                }
            }
        }
        catch(e)
        {
            //alert(e);
        }

    }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Connection time out while accessing jsp using URLConnection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36723057/connection-time-out-while-accessing-jsp-using-urlconnection)

Answer (score 0):

First of all, make sure you are connected to Internet. Then change connection time to zero i.e infinte:

```
servletConnection.setConnectTimeout(0);

//Set read time out to zero if required
servletConnection.setReadTimeout(0);
```